# $_SESSION variable is lost after redirecting using header function

Tags: php, session, redirect

In order to redirect from page 1 to page 2 I've used the header function so :
I have two files :
page1.php :

```
<?php
require_once('model/Manager.php');

function login() {
    $user = getUser($_REQUEST['login']);
    if(!empty($user)) {
        if($_REQUEST['login'] == $user['login'] && $_REQUEST['password'] == $user['password']) {
            $_SESSION['nom'] = $user['login'];
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
            $_SESSION['articles'] = getArticles($user['id']);
            if($user['role'] == 1) {
                header('location: view/Administration.php');
                //require('view/Administration.php');
            }
            else
            require('../view/accueil.php');
        }
        else
            echo 'Erreur Connexion';
}
echo 'Merci de vérifier vos données';
}
```

And
Manager.php :

```
<?php
function dbConnect()
{
    try
    {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mini_projet;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
        return $db;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}

function getUser($login) {
    $db = dbConnect();
    $req = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM utilisateur WHERE login = ?');
    $req->execute(array($_REQUEST['login']));

    $user = $req->fetch();
    
    return $user;
}
```

Router.php

```
<?php
require_once('controller/usercontroller.php');
if (isset($_REQUEST['login']) && isset($_REQUEST['password'])) {
    session_start();
    login();

}
```

Page2.php

```
<?= session_start(); ?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Administration</title>
    <script>
        function validateForm() {
            let x = document.forms["myForm"]["marque"].value;
            if (x == "") {
            document.getElementById("marque_validation").innerHTML = "Merci de remplir ce champ";
            return false;        
  }
} 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   Bienvenue admin : <?php echo $_SESSION['nom'] ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

When trying to redirect to page 2 using the header function as mentionned in the code,
it show me the error : Notice: Undefined index: logged_user in C:\xampp1\htdocs..

it turns out that the session value is lost, please I need help.
PS: I read the other questions related to my problem in stackoverflow but there's no solution.

Comment: You are missing session_start(); at the beginning of page1.php. I cannot execute your code because I don't have the required database setup

Comment: Exactly I've added at the top but nothing change, you can try statically without database just affect a static state for test

Answer (score 0):

You also need to call `session_start()` at the beginning of page1.php.

try:

```php
<?php  # page1.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_user'] = 'joe';
header('location: page2.php');
```

and

```php
<?php  # page2.php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['logged_user'];
```

Comment: I tried but same error

Comment: You missed a ; and why are you calling session_start two times in page2.php?

Comment: I've added the (;) and no change, I didn't call two times bro, just once

Comment: Have you tried the code I provided? If this does not work your browser might not store session cookies.

Comment: yes it worked but when I try to override my original files it won't , I will edit the code to view my original file

Comment: I've edited the code and still the same problem , can you please test the code